# Como esconder a palavra "blog" do meu site wordpress

Tags: htaccess

Sempre que publico um post aparece https://www.site.com.br/blog/assunto/,
gostaria de alterar a URL para https://www.site.com.br/assunto/

Segue meu htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Mais simples do que editar o `htaccess` manualmente, é possível fazer essa configuração direto no painel administrativo do WP. Vá em `Configurações > Links permanentes`. Lá selecione a opção Nome do Post, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa opção resultará em algo semelhante à isso:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hamurabi, então https://www.site.com.br/blog não consigo alterar essa estrutura no wordpress. Gostaria de saber se pelo .htaccess consigo escondero /blog ou mascarar. Grato.

Comment: Tente usar manualmente o código do `.htaccess` que coloquei acima. Uma edição manual do arquivo também dá certo, ressalvo que: se por algum acaso alguém, no painel administrativo do wp, fizer uma alteração na configuração dos links permanentes, o `.htaccess` será sobrescrito e as configs serão perdidas.